# Groovy Bindable default value?

Tags: groovy, bindable, swingbuilder

I would like to have a text field whose value always reflects that of a certain field in a given object. I thought Bindable might be the way to do this. However, using the following example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder
import groovy.beans.Bindable
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE

class TextModel {
    @Bindable String text
}

def textModel = new TextModel()

def builder=new SwingBuilder()
builder.build {
    frame( title: 'Binding Example (Groovy)', size: [240,100], show: true,
          locationRelativeTo: null, defaultCloseOperation: EXIT_ON_CLOSE ) {
        gridLayout cols: 1, rows: 2
        textField id: 'textField'
        bean textModel, text: bind{ textField.text }
        label text: bind{ textModel.text }
    }
}

textModel.text="AAAA"
```

modified from:

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Bindable+and+Vetoable+transformation

only the label text is set to that of textModel, but not that of the textField.

Any ideas???

Thank you
Misha

p.s. I seem to be able to get the opposite behavior, where the TextField reflects that *state* of the variable, but its value is not updated, if I do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder
import groovy.beans.Bindable
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE

class TextModel {
    @Bindable String text
}

def textModel = new TextModel()

def builder=new SwingBuilder()
builder.build {
    frame( title: 'Binding Example (Groovy)', size: [240,100], show: true,
          locationRelativeTo: null, defaultCloseOperation: EXIT_ON_CLOSE ) {
        gridLayout cols: 1, rows: 2
      textField id: 'textField',text:bind{ textModel.text }
        label text: bind{ textModel.text }
    }
}

textModel.text="AAAA"
```

p.p.s. If I add both:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder
import groovy.beans.Bindable
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE

class TextModel {
    @Bindable String text
}

def textModel = new TextModel()

def builder=new SwingBuilder()
builder.build {
    frame( title: 'Binding Example (Groovy)', size: [240,100], show: true,
          locationRelativeTo: null, defaultCloseOperation: EXIT_ON_CLOSE ) {
        gridLayout cols: 1, rows: 2

      textField id: 'textField',text:bind{ textModel.text }
```

bean textModel, text: bind{ textField.text }
            label text: bind{ textModel.text }
        }
    }

```
textModel.text="AAAA"
```

I get

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempt to mutate in notification

p.p.p.s. This is my best solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder
import groovy.beans.Bindable
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE

class TextModel {
    @Bindable String text
}

def textModel = new TextModel()
textModel.text="AAAA"

def builder=new SwingBuilder()
builder.build {
    frame( title: 'Binding Example (Groovy)', size: [240,100], show: true,
          locationRelativeTo: null, defaultCloseOperation: EXIT_ON_CLOSE ) {
        gridLayout cols: 1, rows: 2

      textField id: 'textField',text:textModel.text
```

bean textModel, text: bind{ textField.text }
   label text: bind{ textModel.text }
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

The [Griffon guide on binding](http://dist.codehaus.org/griffon/guide/guide/6.%20Models%20and%20Binding.html#6.2.2%20Additional%20Properties), describes the `mutual` property as being what you want. Even though you're not using Griffon in this case, `bind` seems to be a standard Groovy feature. If you create `textField` like this:

```
  textField id: 'textField', text: bind('text', source: textModel, mutual: true)
```

`textField` will get its initial value from `textModel.text`, write updates to it when the user types in the field, and display the updated value when changes to `textModel.text` occur (from some background thread, say). When I tried to bind *two* text inputs like this, I started getting the IllegalStateExceptions you described, but it seems one input and multiple labels are fine.